# How to properly pass and receive a json object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

From the client, I would like to pass a collection of json nodes: `[{key, value},{key, value}]` to a WebAPI endpoint.  what should my api endpoint param type be?  a List<>() or something else?

This would be using C#.

I need to iterate over each endpoint that is passed in the collection.

Comment: If it's a key value, would you not just use a dictionary?

Comment: perhaps.  Would that be the proper way or just a different way?

Comment: so List<Dictionary<string, string>>()?? could be proper?

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, string>>() is redundunent. Just a dictionary<string,string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is good practice to create a model that your JSON will be deserialized into. To answer your question though if your JSON was in the format

```
[{key1: value1},{key2: value2}]
```

you would be able to use a

```
List<Dictionary<string,object>>()
```

If you were sure that your values were always string values you could do

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>>()
```

As JSON values can be strings (wrapped in quotes), integers (no quotes) or null.

So your Web API controller could be something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ReceiveJSON([FromBody]List<Dictionary<string,string>> in_json)
    {
        // And then one way to iterate over each 'json node' passed
        foreach(var dict in in_json)
        {
         // Do something with dictionary object
        }
        return Ok(in_sjon);
    }
```

What version of ASP.Net Web API will you be using?

Comment: It's actually going to be AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.2

Comment: could I just use Dictionary<string, string>() as the param type and then just iterate over the dictionary?

Comment: Assuming your Json reflects the string you posted: no, you can't. That json is an array of objects, dictionaries can be mapped to objects, not arrays.

Comment: @GregBrethen Very good. I ran my example in ASP.Net Core so this should work for you.